# Меню для диска с видеоуроками

Tags: mediaplayer, flash, html, css

Здраствуйте.
Скажите, пожалуйста, как и при помощи какой программы можно реализовать Flash меню своего диска с видеоуроками? Примеров масса! Вот некоторые из них:  [image]

[image]

И тому подобное. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Собрать полностью рабочее флеш приложение (Flash Pro, Flash Builder), с видео и остальным...
- Создать так называемый "projector" (exe) файл, из существующей флешки, прописать его в `autoexec.cfg` на диске (меню проигрывателя - "Create projector").

Comment: Можно поподробнее со 2 пунктом?
С первым, думаю, справлюсь!)

Comment: Я так понял, чтобы создать рабочее приложение, нужны знания Flash?
Коими я не обладаю.
Посоветуйте что-нибудь для новичков.

Comment: - Запускаем флешку в флеш проигрывателе (проигрыватель должен ставился вместе с Flash Pro или Flash Builder, если нет - скачать с сайта адоба).

 - Внутри плеера, меню Файл -> Создать проектор, появится окно "Сохранить как", выбрать имя и сохранить.

- Теперь флешка завернута внутрь этого запускаемого файла, вместе с плеером, так что должно запускаться на любой машине (даже без флеша), если нужна мак версия, тоже самое проделать на маке, с линухом не знаю как.

Comment: Если что могу сделать меню, обращайтесь.